# jQuery select closest child element by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I use jQuery to get get the text from the rating selected div within the id=overall answer div?

I want to dynamically fetch the text "TESTING" from that div within the overall parent div.

```
<div class='answer' id="overall">
      <div class='rating'>1</div>
      <div class='rating'>2</div> 
      <div class='rating'>3</div>
      <div class='rating'>4</div>
      <div class='rating selected'>TESTING</div>
</div>

<div class='answer' id="effort">
      <div class='rating'>1</div>
      <div class='rating'>2</div> 
      <div class='rating'>3</div>
      <div class='rating selected'>4</div>
      <div class='rating'>TESTING</div>
</div>
```

I tried to do this and it is blank.

```
$(document.getElementById('overall')).find('.rating selected').text();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code *would* work but your selector is wrong. It would be...

```
$(document.getElementById('overall')).find('.rating.selected').text();
```

Notice the dot and no space between `rating` and `selected`.

However, I think you are over complicating things...

```
$('#overall .selected').text();
```

Example...

```js
alert($('#overall .selected').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='answer' id="overall">
      <div class='rating'>1</div>
      <div class='rating'>2</div> 
      <div class='rating'>3</div>
      <div class='rating'>4</div>
      <div class='rating selected'>TESTING - selected</div>
</div>

<div class='answer' id="effort">
      <div class='rating'>1</div>
      <div class='rating'>2</div> 
      <div class='rating'>3</div>
      <div class='rating selected'>4</div>
      <div class='rating'>TESTING - not selected</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

$('#overall .rating.selected').html()